# Retrieving values() from a Map of Sets in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, map, set

I have a map of sets containing ids -

`Map<String,Set<Id>> caseIdsByFlag = new Map<String,Set<Id>>();`

& I'm trying to access the values in the map's sets in an SOQL query

```
List<CaseMilestone> caseMilestones = [SELECT Id, CompletionDate
                                        FROM CaseMilestone
                                       WHERE CaseId IN :caseIdsByFlag.values()];
```

But that's causing an error

> Invalid bind expression type of Set for column of type Id

Is it possible to access the values from a map of sets in an SOQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first combine all the `Set<Id>` into one `Set<Id>` in Apex code:

```
Set<Id> allCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Set<Id> ids : caseIdsByFlag.values()) {
    allCaseIds.addAll(ids);
}

... WHERE CaseId IN :allCaseIds ...
```